# c# Open file on server using alternate credentials using default application

Tags: c#, .net, process

I routinely use Process.Start(file); to open a file (PDF, Work or Excel file typically) using the default application.  However, in this case I need to open a file that is on a server and using different credentials.  I've tried every variation of Process that I can think of and nothing seems to work.

```
string file = folderPath + dlg.listBox1.Items[dlg.listBox1.SelectedIndex].ToString();
Process.Start(file, "xxxx", GetSecureString("xx11xx"), "MyCompany.com");

with this I get "The directory name is invalid".

Process proc = new Process
{
  EnableRaisingEvents = false,
  StartInfo =
    {
      UseShellExecute = false,
      Verb = "open",
      UserName = "xxxx",
      Password = GetSecureString("xx11xx"),
      Domain = "MyCompany.com",
      FileName = folderPath + dlg.listBox1.Items[dlg.listBox1.SelectedIndex].ToString(),
      WorkingDirectory = folderPath,
      Arguments = dlg.listBox1.Items[dlg.listBox1.SelectedIndex].ToString(),
    }
  };
proc.Start();
```

With this, I get is "The specified executable is not a valid Win32 application."

If I drop the folderPath from FileName; i get "The system cannot file the file specified".

By the way, I am using a class I found on StackOverflow to successfully access the folder on the server and copy files to it and list the files in it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You mean using different credentials to access the file? That probably won't be at all easy.

Comment: Yes.  That is exactly what I mean.

Comment: Is it safe to assume that you can, and have tried to, open the file normally? (By double clicking it)  
Is it safe to assume the file extension is registered with the correct executable on the machine that will execute the code? 
I believe you need to look into creating a new thread and attaching a security Principal object to that thread. Use that new thread to launch your process.

Comment: Yes, it is safe to assume all of that.